# Why Java is purely Pass by value?

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

*Why does java doesn't support pass by reference?* 
Is there any specific reason for that?*

Comment: Could you cite an example/doc which says this?

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee - says what?  That Java use purely pass by value?  Try the linked Question for a start.  Or the Java Tutorial.  Or any half decent Java text book.  Or if that's not definitive enough for you, try the JLS.

Comment: @StephenC My comment was posted far before the link was added

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee - not withstanding that, the Java Tutorial, text books, the JLS ... and even Google ... existed before you posted the comment.  Is > 10 years before your comment far enough before for you?

Answer (score 4):

> Why does java doesn't support pass by reference?

[Java is indeed pass-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/367273). However, you can still pass an object reference into a method. Even though the reference is passed by value, the overall effect is almost indistinguishable from pass-by-reference.

What is not supported is references to primitive types.

Comment: +1 for the 'overall' effect statement. I could not frame a coherent sentence that could tell what I wanted to tell

Comment: "the overall effect is indistinguishable from pass-by-reference" Of course not. It is very distinguishable -- with pass-by-reference, you can always assign to a by-reference parameter inside the function, and it will do the same thing as if you assigned (i.e. with `=`) to the passed variable in the calling scope. That is something you cannot do with a pass-by-value language like Java.

Comment: @newacct: That depends on the language. By way of example, C++ has pass-by-reference but none of the semantics that you have outlined (by "assigning to a reference" I assume you mean rebinding the reference to a different object).

Comment: @NPE: I never said "assigning to a reference".

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any specific reason for that?

That is the language design.

It supports pass by reference in a different sense that the reference is passed by value.

See this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Actually in Java everything is passed by value.

When you say Objects are passed by reference, that means Object reference is passed by value.

This is basically a design decision taken by Java designers, to make the language simple and  the code easier to debug.